# shared authentication with cookie and token in identity server

Tags: single-page-application, identityserver4, bearer-token

I’ve an MVC application that uses identity server with cookie based authentication.

We created a new spa application that uses identity server authentication through bearer tokens.

Everything works fine, but the user is currently required to log in twice, once in each app.

Is there a solution to share the authentication session? I would prefer to not have to decrypt the cookie from the spa if possible.

Edit:

What I see is that the authentication code flow on the SPA is populating a lot of values on the session storage, which are not picked up by the the MVC (client credentials flow) application.

Am I supposed to reflect those changes manually? I see that both populate a cookie with the security information, but the SPA is just ignoring it.

[image]

Comment: If you’re using a flow like implicit or authorization_code then you should be getting SSO out of the box. Can you explain what factors might be preventing that from working?

Comment: I've seen that after the authorization code I get a sso cookie, but it gets ignored by the application using client credentials (meaning that I get asked for the login a second time). The same happens in the other direction (client credentials first, then authorization code)

Comment: You won't get (and don't need) SSO when using client credentials. You'll only get it when using a browser-based user-context flow.

Comment: Both apps are using a browser-based user-context flow. The client credentials one is a .net mvc app, the authentication code is a .net core SPA app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the reason was due to the difference in casing for the Authentication/authentication endpoint.
The cookies for idsrv and idsrvsession were marked as case sensitive, so we ended up having two different cookies for the session (hence creating 2 different sessions).

Changing one of the two endpoint to match the other solved the issue, although a CR forcing a tolowercase of the parameter has been requested to the library performing  the connection to identity server.